# Mysql query for getting unique rows

Tags: mysql

I have table named 'testing' of 3 columns i.e. user,score,time in that 'time' is unique and user,score is repeated with different score. like below

```
user |   score  |   time
----------------------------
535  | 17       | 1279170280
535  | 1        | 1279170693
100  | 55       | 1279171361
100  | 30       | 1279171412
535  | 2        | 1279173412
595  | 4        | 1279173539
595  | 22       | 1279173571
595  | 50       | 1279173775
```

now how do i get high scored users uniquely. please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get you a list of the highest score per each user.

```
select user, max(score) from table group by user
```

If you want the top 10, just add limit

```
select user, max(score) from table group by user limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  user,
  max(score)
FROM
 testing
GROUP BY
 user
```

this should do it ..

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from testing join 
     (select max(score) score, user 
      from testing 
      group by user) high using (score, user)
```

This should give you the highest score, the user# and the time of that score if that's what you wanted.
If you don't need the time, you can execute only the inner query